# JAXB writing to OutputStream inside writeTo method

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws, jax-rs

I have been trying to write a String directly to OutputStream inside the writeTo implementation method of MessageBodyWriter interface. I want to do this inside a try catch block to send a message when an exception gets caught. However, when I debug through the program, I realize that the String never gets written to the OutputStream (size = -1).

The code looks something like this:

```
public void writeTo(final Object entityObject, final Class<?> aClass, final Type type,
                        final Annotation[] annotations, final MediaType mediaType,
                        final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> stringObjectMultivaluedMap,
                        final OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
   try{
     throw new JAXBException("error");
   }catch(JAXBException j){
     outputStream.write("HI".getBytes());
     outputStream.flush();
   }
```

Comment: and a log statement if unsure. What happens if you flush or close the stream?

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. I have tried flushing but still no go.

Comment: Are your outputStream calls generating exceptions?

Comment: may be IOException but even when I caught it still nothing gets written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER**

You could leverage the WebApplicationException that can be thrown from the *writeTo* method in *MessageBodyWriter*.

```
public void writeTo(DataObject dataObject, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> multivaluedMap, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    try {
        throw new JAXBException("error");
    } catch(JAXBException e) {
        Response response = Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                                     .entity("HI")
                                     .type("text/plain")
                                     .build();
        throw new WebApplicationException(response);
    }
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

In my opinion you are better of throwing the JAXBException from the MessageBodyWriter, and then creating an ExceptionMapper to log the problem:

```
@Provider
public class JAXBExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JAXBException> {

    public Response toResponse(JAXBException e) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                       .entity(e.getMessage());
                       .type("text/plain").build();
    }

}
```

This will allow you to return a response code that indicates that a problem occurred.

Comment: Thank you Blaise. The reason why I am not doing it your way is that the the exception (Runtime) thrown inside my class (extends MessageBodyWriter) does not get caught by the mapper that I have created. I am doing this manually by trying to write the error message to the outputstream

Comment: ExceptionMapper should be able to catch Runtime exceptions.  You could always create your own exception class.  Have your MessageBodyWrtier wrap any exceptions thrown with your exception.  And create the ExceptionMapper for your own exception type.

Comment: that's exactly what I did. I created my own exception and throw it inside my class like catch(JAXBException e) { throw new MyException("HI");}. I also have a mapper for that specific exception. For some reason whenever I try to throw an exception inside this class it is not caught by the mapper. Instead it returns something like java.lang.IllegalStateException: STREAM

Comment: Have you tried creating an ExceptionMapper of a more generic type like Exception or Throwable to see what does get caught?

Comment: Yes I have RuntimeException mapper

Comment: Have you also tried throwing a WebApplicationException from the writeTo method in MessageBodyWriter?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I have not tried it but throwing exception is the thing that I want to avoid in this case because I 'believe' that throwing any kind of exception will just trigger the weird exception that I just showed you. If I understand this correctly, I just want to catch the exception but inside the catch I want to modify the outputstream because I believe whatever is written in the outputstream will eventually be displayed on the user's browser.

Comment: The WebApplicationException wraps a Response, and it is the Response that will be returned to the browser and not the problematic outputStream.

Comment: Blaise. I tried to do what you suggested, throwing WebApplicationException and I got this. Jan 31, 2011 1:57:55 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _handleRequest.
SEVERE: The response of the WebApplicationException cannot be utilized as the response is already committed. Re-throwing to the HTTP container
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException